# GuzzleHttp doesnt show response from a nodejs server

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, guzzle

I'm using `GuzzleHttp`. I want to send request from laravel to nodejs.

```
    try {

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = 'http://localhost:8085/api/test/get';
        $headers = [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ];


        $res = $client->post($url, [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'json' => $data,
        ]);
        dd($res->getBody());
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {

       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

my request sent as well, but `$res->getBody()` doesn't show my nodejs result. (I sure nodejs has response)

my nodejs code:

```
   total_result            = _res.length
    response.total_result   = total_result
    response.result         = _res
    console.log(response)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.status(200).json(response);
```

The result of `dd($res->getBody());` is:

```
Stream {#2694
  -stream: stream resource @1095
    wrapper_type: "PHP"
    stream_type: "TEMP"
    mode: "w+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "php://temp"
    options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solved. You should use an asynchronous request:

```
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org');
$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});

$promise->wait();
```

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle